# Show that if $A$ is the Banach algebra generated by $\{1_A,x\}$, then $Sp(A) \cong Sp_A(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital commutative complex Banach algebra. Suppose that $x \in A$ such that the Banach algebra generated by $\{1_A,x\}$ equals $A$. Show that the natural map

$$Sp(A) \to Sp_A(x): \chi \mapsto \chi(x)$$

is a homeomorphism.

I managed to show that this map is well-defined, continuous and injective. Homeomorphism will follow from the compact domain and the Hausdorff codomain once I have shown this is surjective.

In order to show this is surjective, I'm trying to show that if $\lambda \in Sp(A)$ and $J:= \overline{(x-\lambda)} \unlhd A$, then

$$A/J \cong \mathbb{C}$$

I try to apply isomorphism theorems for this. In order to do this, I need to define a surjective map $A \to \mathbb{C}$ with kernel equal to $J$.

So let $a \in A$. Then there are polynomials $P_n \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $a = \lim_n P_n(x)$. I guess the obvious image of a map with codomain $\mathbb{C}$ would be $\lim_n P_n(\lambda)$, but then I have to show two things:

(1) This does not depend on the chosen sequence.

(2) The limit actually exists.

I don't manage to prove both these things, and I'm unsure it is even true.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $x$, check that $J=(x-\lambda)\cdot A$ is 1. not all of $A$, 2. an ideal, 3. closed, 4. a maximal ideal. Hence the quotient $A/J$ is a normed field over $\Bbb C$, which means it must be $\Bbb C$. So the quotient map $A\to J/A\cong \Bbb C$ is an algebra-morphism into $\Bbb C$, this is a character. Further it sends $(x-\lambda)$ to $0$, so it must send $x$ to $\lambda$.

Comment: @s.harp  Thanks. I can show all of this except that $J$ is maximal. Why is that the case? This seems the crux of the matter.

Comment: An element of $x$ can be represented as a power series $y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-\lambda)^n$ (although not necessarily in a unique manner. Here $a_n$ is so that $\sum_n |a_n|\,\|(x-\lambda)\|^n$ converges. Once you have this it elementary that if you take something not in $J$ it must differ from an element of $J$ only by something invertible. To see that statement note that elements of that form clearly are a Banach-algebra containing $1$ and $x$ in which polynomials are dense.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to manage with your hints!